# Ratio of the number of solutions to unit fraction equations with shifted prime and natural denominators

Tags: nt.number-theory, asymptotics, unit-fractions

In a 2018 [question posed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316474/can-we-write-each-positive-rational-number-as-frac1p-1-1-ldots-frac1p-k-1/446198#446198) by Zhi-Wei Sun, he conjectures that for any rational number $r>0$, there are finite sets $P_r^-$ and $P_r^+$ of primes such that
$$r=\sum_{p\in P_r^-}\frac1{p-1}=\sum_{p\in P_r^+}\frac1{p+1}.$$
Recently, Thomas Bloom has answered this question, and has published a [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.02689) on the ArXiv in which a proof is presented that affirms this conjecture. In case the denominators can be any natural number, it is already well-known such a representation (often called an Egyptian fraction) exists for every rational number.

Define $$E_{n} := \left\{ \{x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots, x_{n} \} \subset \mathbb{N}: 1=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{1\over x_{i}} \text{ where } x_{1} < x_{2} < \dots < x_{n} \right\} , $$

and $$S_{n} := \left\{\{y_{1}, y_{2}, \dots, y_{n} \} \subset \mathbb{P}: 1=\sum_{j=1 }^{n}{1\over {y_{j}-1}} \text{ where } y_{1} < y_{2} < \dots < y_{n} \right\} . $$

Moreover, let $e(n) := |E_{n}|$, and $s(n) := |S_{n}| $.

The behaviour of $e(\cdot)$ has been studied in the past. For instance, the following [master's thesis](https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/90573/Crawford_MB_T_2019.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) describes how $e(8)$ can be obtained (it is not *exactly* this number though, as the author considers the case where the denominators need not be distinct). Also, it is known that $e(\cdot)$ is [bounded from below](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S0001434614010295) by a double exponential function.

I wonder how $e(\cdot)$ and $s(\cdot)$ relate to one another. Comparing the growth rates of these two functions may yield some insights into [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433904/a-weighted-count-of-egyptian-fraction-representations).

**Questions**:

1. Let $f(n) := e(n)/s(n)$. What can be said about $L := \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)$ ?
2. What are the asymptotics of $f(\cdot)$? Can one obtain upper and lower bounds?